# The model backing the <MyContext> context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a data layer that uses Code First with **EF 6.0.0.0** and I'm using Fluent API. I ran enable-migrations, add-migrations, and update-database and got the database created in SQL Server.

Then I created a unit test in another project with a reference to the data layer and ran it without any issues. The problem started when I added a new property to one of the Code First classes. I ran add-migrations and update-database again and saw the changes reflected in SQL Server...so far so good. 
But when I try to use the new class in the project containing the unit tests, I get the following exception:

> "The model backing the <MyContext> context has changed since the
>   database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update
>   the database"

...where <MyContext> is my context class. The data layer library is in sync with the database so why can't the unit tests be run?

After looking through stackoverflow I tried adding:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
```

...which shut up the exception about the model changing, but then created a new problem:

> "Invalid column name 'Description'."

...where 'Description' is the new property added to the data layer class (and the new SQL Server column).

The unit-test project is in the same solution as the data-layer project and has a "project" reference to the data-layer dll.

Why does EF think that the data model and the database are out of sync? and why does it think that 'Description' is an invalid column name? But of course what I really want to know is how to get this working?

Since I first posted this I used SQL Server Profiler to see the SQL generated during SaveChanges() and the script will run as expected in SS Management Studio which suggests to me that there is nothing wrong with the column name, yet that is what the DbUpdateException is reporting.

Comment: please use code mark up for greater readability in your question .

Comment: Just in case the issue was related to the unit test framework I created a stub console app to use the data layer but got the same behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the database being used in the unit test project, that gets it's connection string from the project's app.config, is not the same as the one being used in the webapp project, that gets it's connection string from the project's web.config.

So, instead of using

```
Database.SetInitializer(null);
```

try

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<{YourDbContext}, Configuration>());
```

You can check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx#initializer

Best,

Comment: Thanks for replying. I checked the link you mentioned and tried the change but I still get the "Invalid column name" exception. The migrations had already created the column in the database so I suspect that there's nothing wrong with the migrations.

Comment: Would you post the conection string section of web.config for the web app and app.config for the unit test, and the initialization code for the DbContext?.

Check also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592674.aspx

Comment: BTW, it's better if you upgrade to the latest EF!

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this happen when working on a team using some sort of source control.  One developer will make EntityModel changes update the DB and fail to let others know they need to pull the latest code down.

In your case, if you are all alone, I suggest you clear the BIN folder for the Unit Tests and then recompile.  It sounds like the DLL it copied over for the Unit Test Project may not be up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it but got the same issues: either the "context has changed" exception or the "invalid column name" exception. The new property in the data-layer class shows up in intellisense in the unit-test project and everything compiles ok which suggests to me that the references and dll's are ok.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone experiencing the issue where their Unit Tests are failing with the "Context has changed" error but their main app is working; for me it was that the unit tests were using a different connection string.  To perform an update-database correctly I used this command from package console:

```
update-database -ProjectName MyProj.EntityFramework -StartUpProjectName MyProj.IntegrationTests -Verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is drop the tables which were generated from the model.
Moreover, make sure that you drop `_MigrationHistory` table as well.  Then re-run your code.

Problem solved